# python 2.7 interpreter exits when calling opencv's SURF detect keypoints

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, surf

I'm trying to compute an image's keypoints and features usinf SURF. I wrote the following script for Python 2.7:

```
import cv2

# load image and conver to grayscale
ima=cv2.imread('image.png')
ima2 = cv2.cvtColor(ima, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# create object to extract keypoints
surf_detector=cv2.FeatureDetector_create("SURF")

# extract those keypoints
keypoints = surf_detector.detect(ima2)
```

Reaching the last line of the script python exits without warning nor error message. ¿Any clues of what might be happening and how to fix this?

Comment: Works fine for me. I used a JPEG image though. Try using one?

Comment: Tried, JPEG gives the same result. Image format shouldn't make any diference (right?).

Answer (score 0):

Problem aparently "fixed itself" after (yet another) reinstallation of OpenCV from scratch following the instructions at http://danwin.com/2014/12/compile-opencv-2-4-10-ubuntu-14-04-14-10/